# modifiedCount is 1 even though the document didn't change

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using a simple `updateOne` query where I pull an ObjectId out of an array.

```js
await this.portfolioModel.updateOne(
  {
    _id: portfolioId,
    'watchlist.custom._id': watchlistId
  },
  {
    $pull: {
      'watchlist.custom.$.assets': assetId
    }
  }
)
```

But I want to detect if the document actually changed or if the assetIds wasn't in the array to begin with. The problem is that even though the document hasn't changed MongoDB still returns `modifiedCount` with `1`.

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

I checked the document and the `__v` doen't increment with the updates so I don't know why MongoDB thinks the document has changed.

This is how the document looks (before and after update):

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "600188dab0b1c70050084e3e"
  },
  "watchlist": {
    "all": [],
    "custom": [
      {
        "assets": [],
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "624d7a18c89b3937212b3a55"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "__v": 18,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-05-11T22:19:05.450Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2022-04-06T11:45:37.415Z"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the document before the update _and_ after the update? How did you get the `modifiedCount`? You can also, use `findOneAndUpdate` which can return the updated document.

Comment: @prasad_ I updated the question to show the document. It does not change after the update. Even the `updatedAt` property by mongoose doesn't reflect any changes. `modifiedCount` and the other properties are directly returned from `updateOne()`.

Comment: Your update statement works as it is; it is syntactically correct. Make sure you are verifying the correct collection/database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered this same issue using mongoose 6.3.5 and MongoDB serverless version 5.3.1.

The fix for me was removing `{timestamps: true}` from my schema. This causes the document to be 'modified' even if no change was made to its values. I believe it is because the 'updatedAt' value would change whenever `updateOne()` would access the document.

Comment: true :) I figured this out after a while